# XCode error when trying to run Unity3D app

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am trying to run my iOS app that I developed in Unity on XCode but I am getting this error:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _gEnableStylusTouch
>         Referenced from: /Users//Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/91CAEC4E-6706-4B87-AA7A-323CB629C56E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E591C7A6-EA53-470E-BDF0-8CF2C3DDF686/dsapp.app/dsapp
>         Expected in: flat namespace
>        in /Users//Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/91CAEC4E-6706-4B87-AA7A-323CB629C56E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E591C7A6-EA53-470E-BDF0-8CF2C3DDF686/dsapp.app/dsapp

This is only happening when I am running on the **iPhone6** simulator. It works on all the simulators before iPhone6.

Here are some details of my environment:

**Unity3D version:** 5.3.3f1

**XCode version:** 7.2.1

Does anyone know how I can get rid of this error, I have read other related questions that say this problem has to do with linked frameworks and libraries but I am still unsure of how I can solve this issue. Any help is appreciated.

### EDIT

### Note that I am also getting this error when I submit to the apple store. It needs to be fixed otherwise I can't get my app in the store.

Added screenshots below.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Indeed sounds like a build phase related problem. Would you be able to provide some screenshots of your **Build Phase** and probably the `framework search path` within the **Build Settings**?

Comment: @J.Wang I added requested screenshots

Comment: Make sure you have the right command line tools selected see this screenshot for details http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cw8p.png

Comment: @MahmoudFayez I do have it selected.

Comment: Please reset the simulator to avoid any conflicts

Comment: https://karp.id.au/post/xcode_7_linker_rules/

Comment: Try this : 1. Delete derived Data at  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
2. Clean build (Cmd+Shift+K)
3. Re-run on device, after all the indexing and such was finished (dispayed at the top of xcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Unity3D player settings for iOS, I changed the scripting backend from Mono to IL2CPP and selected Universal as my architecture and it worked. I submitted to the apple store with no errors and it was successfully reviewed and accepted. I'm not exactly sure why it solved the issue, I was just fiddling around with different options.